# Link image position and size to figure's dpi

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a method to link image position and size to figure's dpi?

With the code below I'm be able to plot a chart.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=100)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=0.95, bottom=0)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
ax1.set_title(sensing_date)
ax1.set_xticks([], [])
ax1.set_yticks([], [])

# Remove black border
for spine in ['top', 'right', 'left', 'bottom']:
    ax1.spines[spine].set_visible(False)

# Add raster
imshow(
    data,
    ax=ax1,
    vmin=0,
    vmax=255,
    add_colorbar=False,
    add_labels=False,
)

# Add scalebar
scalebar = ScaleBar(
    dx=1.0,
    border_pad=1.0,
    location='lower left'
)
ax1.add_artist(scalebar)

# Add images
esa = plt.imread(logo_list[1])
ax1.figure.figimage(esa, 880, 880, alpha=1.0, zorder=1)

copernicus = plt.imread(logo_list[2])
ax1.figure.figimage(copernicus, 850, 820, alpha=1.0, zorder=1)

sentinel2 = plt.imread(logo_list[3])
ax1.figure.figimage(sentinel2, 880, 760, alpha=1.0, zorder=1)

mio_logo = plt.imread(logo_list[0])
ax1.figure.figimage(mio_logo, 900, 700, alpha=1.0, zorder=1)

plt.savefig(images.joinpath(file_name))
```

[image]

But if I change the `dpi` to 200 the result is this:
[image]